# Make Https request with the netty4-http component of Apache Camel

Tags: ssl, https, apache-camel, netty

I exposed a simple REST service with Apache Camel like Spring boot microservice, which creates a request to a service in https, using the netty4-http component.

```
public class RoutingTest extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        restConfiguration()
            .host("localhost")
            .port("8080");

        rest().post("test") 
        .route()
            .setBody(constant("message=Hello"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethod.POST))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
            .to("netty4-http:https://localhost/service/test");
    }
}
```

When i call `http://localhost:8080/test`, I get 400 Bad Request error when the routing call `https://localhost/service/test` service.From the logs I read that the request arrives in HTTP  instead HTTPS format and I don't understand why:

> You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port. Instead use
>   the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.

If I invoke the service `https://localhost/service/test` with Postman, it works correctly.

SSL is configured with a Self-signed certificate.

How do I create a correct https request with the netty component in apache camel? The documentation only suggests the replacement of the protocol, at most a few options which however do not work.

**UPDATE (SOLVED SEE BELOW)**

I updated the call in this way

```
.to("netty4-http:https://localhost/dpm/idp/oauth/token?ssl=true&sslContextParameters=#sslContextParameters");
```

The `ssl = true` parameter is mandatory and I have also configured the bean for `SSLContextParameters` like this:

```
@Bean(name = "sslContextParameters")
public static SSLContextParameters sslParameters() throws KeyManagementException, GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource("C:/myfolder/test.jks");

    KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
    kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
    kmp.setKeyPassword("jskPassword");      

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
    SSLContext sslcontext = builder.build();
    scp.createSSLContext().setDefault(sslcontext);

    return scp;
}
```

I am fighting a bit with the classes that are deprecated. For testing I leave only one method deprecated because I should work with inheritance.

If I understood correctly, I had to generate a `JKS` file for the trust zone, starting from my self-signed certificates (.crt and .key files). Once done, I added the instructions for the `KeyStoreParameters` with the password.

It is almost solved, but now I am getting this error when i execute the

> PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to [configure a `sslContextParameters` object](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-configuration-utilities.html) that you can use to [configure the Netty component](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/netty4-http-component.html#_http_options) for SSL.

I am not sure about the parameter name. The docs say `sslContextParameters`, but I thought it was `sslContextParametersRef`.

```
.to("netty4-http:https://localhost/service/test?sslContextParametersRef=#sslConfig");
```

The `#sslConfig` means that Camel can get the object from the registry with the identifier `sslConfig`. So for example with Spring this would be a Spring managed Bean with ID `sslConfig`.

The [Netty component](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/netty4-component.html) (not http) also has a parameter `ssl=true`. No idea if this is also needed for [Netty-http](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/netty4-http-component.html). So you will have to test a bit with these different parameters.

By the way the docs of the Netty component have [an SSL example with context parameter configuration](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/netty-component.html#_an_ssltcp_based_netty_consumer_endpoint_using_request_reply_communication) etc. Have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was just modifying the following code when reported from that documentation and others, but now I'm a little confused. I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Some instructions needed for the self-signed certificate were missing. 
Below is the complete bean.

```
@Bean(name = "sslContextParameters")
public static SSLContextParameters sslParameters() throws KeyManagementException, GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource("C:/myfolder/test.jks");
    ksp.setPassword("jskPassword");

    KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
    kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
    kmp.setKeyPassword("jskPassword");

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
    SSLContext sslcontext = builder.build();
    scp.createSSLContext().setDefault(sslcontext);

    // Necessary for the the self-signed server certificate
    TrustManagersParameters tmp = new TrustManagersParameters();
    tmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
    scp.setTrustManagers(tmp);

    return scp;
}
```

As for the `test.jks` file, I created it with `keytool`, the tool supplied with the `JDK` for managing certificates (creation, export and import).
In my case having already created the certificate with `OpenSSL`, I had to create only the `JKS (Java Keystore)` file to be imported. For it is necessary to convert the certificate in the `P12` file (it should be an archive) and finally in the `JKS`.

During the operations you will be asked to enter passwords for both files

```
- openssl pkcs12 -export -in test.crt -inkey test.key -out test.p12
- keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore test.p12 -destkeystore test.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12
- keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore test.jks -destkeystore test.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

here test is the name of my certificate file. The last operation is not mandatory but it is recommended by keytool itself in order to migrate the `JKS` format, proprietary format if I understand correctly, to the more common `PKCS12` format.

The value `jskPassword` in the code is the password I set when creating the keystore.

I hope it will help.