# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component netty is not a RestConsumerFactory

Tags: https, apache-camel, netty, java-17

I'm  trying to use netty component ,But I'm getting follwing error.I tried jeety also.But it didnt work.Im using camel 3.21.0 and java version is 17.Any help is useful.

```
   RestConfigurationDefinition restDefinition = restConfiguration()
            .endpointProperty("maxThreads", "#maxThreads")
            .endpointProperty("minThreads", "#minThreads")
            .endpointProperty("requestBufferSize", "#requestBufferSize") 
            .endpointProperty("responseBufferSize", "#responseBufferSize") 
            .endpointProperty("requestHeaderSize", "#requestHeaderSize") 
            .endpointProperty("useXForwardedForHeader", "#useXForwardedForHeader")
            .endpointProperty("matchOnUriPrefix", "#matchOnUriPrefix")
            .endpointProperty("bridgeErrorHandler", "true")
            .endpointProperty("sendServerVersion", "false")
            .endpointProperty("socketConnectorProperties", "#socketConnectorProperties")
            .endpointProperty("secureSocketProtocol", "TLSv1.3")
            .endpointProperty("ssl","true")
            .endpointProperty("sslKeyPassword", "WalletPasswd123")
            .endpointProperty("sslPassword", "WalletPasswd123")
            .endpointProperty("sslContextParameters", "#sslContextParameters")
            .enableCORS(true)
            .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .bindingMode(endpointConfig.getRestBindingMode() != null ?
                    endpointConfig.getRestBindingMode() : RestBindingMode.off)
            .apiComponent("netty")
            .component("netty")
            .scheme("https")
            .host(endpointConfig.getHost())
            .port(endpointConfig.getPort());



Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component netty is not a RestConsumerFactory
    at org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestEndpoint.createConsumer(RestEndpoint.java:482) ~[camel-rest-3.21.0.jar:3.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.gatherRootServices(DefaultRoute.java:636) ~[camel-base-engine-3.21.0.jar:3.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.gatherServices(DefaultRoute.java:620) ~[camel-base-engine-3.21.0.jar:3.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.initializeServices(DefaultRoute.java:205) ~[camel-base-engine-3.21.0.jar:3.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doSetup(RouteService.java:151) ~[camel-base-engine-3.21.0.jar:3.21.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.setUp(RouteService.java:130) ~[camel-base-engine-3.21.0.jar:3.21.0]
```

I'm expecting to use netty to enable ssl in rest requests.

Answer (score 1):

netty is a socket communication component, you need to use netty-http component for REST. apiComponent might not be required, as its for different purpose.

And I can see you have configured some properties specific to jetty. You need to specify parameters specific to netty-http component. You can check the docs for [Rest DSL](https://camel.apache.org/manual/rest-dsl.html),[Netty HTPP](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/netty-http-component.html),[Jetty](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/jetty-component.html) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792617/make-https-request-with-the-netty4-http-component-of-apache-camel) answer for more details.